# I set 'PropTypes' to 'string', but, print 3

Tags: reactjs

I am a complete starter. It will be an easy question for the experts. Sorry to have a very basic question.

I set 'PropTypes' to 'string' in MyComponent.js.
And I set 'name' to 3 in App.js.

I think an error should occur. But it prints 3. Why?

https://codesandbox.io/s/qkm4p67409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When an invalid value is provided for a prop, a warning will be shown in the JavaScript console. For performance reasons, propTypes is only checked in development mode.

your project throw an error but show in console only.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have set **default** property in **MyComponent**

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
      name: "MY default name is kang suk lee"
    };
```

But you have **Modify** it with **3** in **App** Component

```
<MyComponent name={3} />
```

That's way it **replace** default Props "**MY default name is kang suk lee**" to **3**.